# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_default_renderer'

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

Im installing the ckeditor app in my django, follow the instructions from [ckeditor documentation](http://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django-ckeditor) at the moment of run the runserver, doesn't works, well,I get the error when add the `from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField` in the models.py

This is my settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'suj4$h^8p&x#p_#i$_p&z@&d^46=#7kf6a#_tkqh68er^)872s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'ckeditor',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Django Suit configuration example
SUIT_CONFIG = {
     'ADMIN_NAME': 'Inicia sesión cabrón',
     'HEADER_DATE_FORMAT': 'l, j. F Y',
     'HEADER_TIME_FORMAT': 'H:i',
     'SEARCH_URL': '/admin/auth/user/',
     'MENU_ICONS': {
        'sites': 'icon-leaf',
        'auth': 'icon-lock',
     },
     'MENU_OPEN_FIRST_CHILD': True, # Default True
     'MENU_EXCLUDE': ('auth.group',),
     'MENU': (
         'sites',
         {'app': 'auth', 'icon':'icon-lock', 'models': ('user', 'group')},
         {'label': 'Settings', 'icon':'icon-cog', 'models': ('auth.user', 'auth.group')},
         {'label': 'Blog', 'icon':'icon-play-circle', 'url': 'blog.post'},
     ),
}

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = {
    '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/',
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7ff7671a0268>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/blog/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "/home/francisco/work/django/blog/Django-Blog/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.forms.widgets import get_default_renderer
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_default_renderer'
```

Answer (score 8):

I met the same problem. It's due to the version of ckeditor and the version of Django you use. My current `django==1.9.8` which is not supported by `django-ckeditor==5.6.1`

My solution :

```
pip install django-ckeditor==5.3.0
```

If your Django version is between 1.8 and 1.10, this may work as well.

The Author has fixed this issue and updated in Github recently.

Answer (score 3):

There is a version difference between the version of ckeditor you are using and the version used in the project. This same error was faced by me when I tried to run a pre-existing project.

Comment: I have: 

Django==1.9
django-ckeditor==5.6.1
django-js-asset==1.1.0
django-suit==0.2.25

What version do you suggest I get?
thank you!

Comment: Once try with django-ckeditor==5.3.0. Any other package doesn't seem to create an error.

Comment: I tried to remove the project and install once again the 'suit' app and 'ckeditor' app, ckeditor dont needs a special configuration, just add the 'suit' to INSTALLED_APPS first and the brand new 'ckeditor', the versions that works its : django-suit==0.2.25 django-ckeditor==5.6.1 Django==1.11.14, the people can see in the next repository: git@github.com:fsifuentesm/django-blog.git tks @Vishal B.